# Using org.eclipse.compare plug in

Tags: eclipse-plugin, compare, eclipse-rcp

I want to develop compare plugin using eclipse compare framework.
Compare plugin intended to develop should be able to count differences not just show them.
How can I know a way to execute "Compare with each other" action on context menu ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here... Do you want to invoke compare action (command) from your own code or add a new action to that context menu?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very abstract. At first you can start from [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_a_compare_editor?). This example shows you how to create compare editor and open it.

Comment: The address of this FAQ was changed to http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_a_compare_editor%3F